# didEnterRegion call multiple time when network changed (3G To Wifi) in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, cllocationmanager

My below is working fine when Travel but at same place I change my network from 3G to Wifi and vice versa then didEnterRegion called multiple times.

Any once have any idea to resolve?

```
 func initLocationManager() {
         self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 200
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
   }
```

Following Code for Start Monitoring Region

```
let clampedRadius = (radius > locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance) ? locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance : radius

let geotification = Geotification(coordinate: coordinate, RadiusMetres: clampedRadius, PointOfInterestId: PointOfInterestId, note: note, eventType: eventType,EventId:EventId ,distanceBetCurrentAndRegionLatLong: self.haversine(self.latitude, lon1: self.longitude, lat2: coordinate.latitude, lon2: coordinate.longitude))

self.startMonitoringGeotification(geotification)
```

//http://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift [I am following this link]

```
  func startMonitoringGeotification(geotification: Geotification) {
        // 1
        if !CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailableForClass(CLCircularRegion) {
            //alert
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: ALERT_TITLE, message: ALERT_GEOFANCING_NOT_SUPPORT_ON_DEVICE, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: ALERT_OK, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil))
            self.navigationController?.topViewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return
        }
        // 2
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .AuthorizedAlways {
            //alert
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: ALERT_TITLE, message: ALERT_GRANT_GEOTIFY_PERMISSION, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: ALERT_OK, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil))
            self.navigationController?.topViewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        // 3 Most Important method [Here Region set]
        let region = getRegionFromGeotification(geotification)
        // 4
        if locationManager != nil
        {
            locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
        }
    }
```

Location Delegates called multiple time's when changed network 3G to Wifi and viceversa.

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {


}
```

Important : When distance change 200m then I have stopped all region and start nearest 20 region.

Comment: how is your region defined?

Comment: I have updated question...Do you need more information?

Comment: Are you getting corresponding calls to `didExitRegion`? What is the size of your region?  How long between the calls to `didExitRegion` and `didEnterRegion` ?

Comment: Yes..Region radius is 50meters

Comment: @SaumilShah Can you explain how exactly you "change network from 3G to WiFi"? Do you enable WiFi to switch from 3G to WiFi, and disable WiFi to switch back to 3G?

Comment: Yes 1. change network from 3G to WiFi -> got multiple exit  2. WiFi to switch from 3G to WiFi -> got multiple entry